# SQL Aggregate Function with XML fields

Tags: sql, xml, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a SQL Query (basic at first, will build up as I get the foundation down) that involves iterating through an XML field(s).  In short, I want to get the Count(*) for each Country name right now.

```
SELECT 

    CAST(ShippingAddress AS XML).value('(/Address//CountryName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ShippingCountry,
    COUNT(*)

FROM test_Order
GROUP BY ShippingCountry
```

I can't seem to GROUP BY the ShippingCountry as the column doesn't exist just yet.  Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wrap the initial `Select` into a subquery, See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     --You can wrap the initial query of the XML in a subquery
     --Then do a select on the subquery doing your aggregate COUNT with GroupBy

     SELECT x.[ShippingCountry], COUNT(x.[ShippingCountry]) AS [ShippingCountryCount]
     FROM
     (
       SELECT CAST(ShippingAddress AS XML).value('(/Address//CountryName/node())[1]', 
       'nvarchar(max)') AS ShippingCountry,
       FROM test_Order
     ) AS x
    GROUP BY x.[ShippingCountry]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It worked great.  I would upvote this, but apparently I'm too new to do that quite yet.

Comment: @JohnPete22 You're welcome. Don't worry about the upvoting, no worries. If you generate enough reputation, you can always stop back and give it an up-tick. :)